# sprintf , do not printing time(0) and other values

Tags: c++, time, timestamp, printf

i am trying to print timestamp and int value : 543

i think problem in format,

```
char buffer [50];
sprintf (buffer, "Time : %d , ID %d",time(0),543);
```

it print the timestamp correct but the ID is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using %d to print a `time_t`, which assumes `time_t` is an `int`. This may not be true, it might be another, larger type - it's even allowed to be a floating point type,  and that would cause trouble since you've promised printf that you are passing in an int.

There's no printf format specifier to print a time_t, but you could cast and print it as a long long which would be ok on platforms that uses an integer type for time_t that's 64 bits or less (which is most platforms):

```
 sprintf (buffer, "Time : %lld , ID %d",(long long)time(0),543);
```

Answer (score 0):

Much preferable way would be to use `ctime` to convert from `time_t` into a string and print that.

Or, you can extract required info from `time_t` into `struct tm` using `gmtime` or `localtime` and print members from that or further use `strftime` on `struct tm` and print time as a string.

The C standard specifies that `time_t` is real, so it can be either integer or floating value(C11: 6.2.5.17) So, if you must print `time_t` value, then you could use `%lld`(long long) or `%Lf`(long double) for printing it.